# Can I use Raspberry Pi to log into an account and print information from a certain page?

Tags: home-automation, login, printing

I run a small gift basket business and am always looking for solutions to make my day easier. One thing that slows me down is having to print gift messages for each basket.

I was wondering if there was a way to use Raspberry Pi to login to the dashboard of my website, see if new orders came in, and if they did, copy the text from the gift message box and print it. I'm planning on purchasing a printer that can print a single gift message card at a time.

Basically I want the combination of this new printer and Raspberry Pi to automatically print the gift message each time I get a new order. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. How easy it will be depends on your knowledge and skills.

Comment: How difficult would this be to do for an experienced person? How about for someone with basic coding skills?

Comment: Not very difficult assuming authentication is straightforward. Python might be a good language for this app because it has lots of "libraries" (reusable code). Note that if you store "credentials" on the RPi, you're creating some additional risk exposure if your RPi gets stolen or hacked. There might be better options; more info might help us help you.

Comment: This can be done on any computer. The Pi is a computer so YES.

Comment: @Logan one thing you can do is check if your website has an `API`. This will make it far easier for you to download the order information because it will be in a data format. For example the API might provide a `JSON` document which is an array of the order information. Please give me a shout if you need more help with this.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! We are currently using a Mac to run the business. Are there certain platforms you would recommend to build this out?

Comment: Frankly I would run on the Mac